# AjaxOptions.HttpMethod = GET results in method=POST

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-ajax

I have the following `AjaxOptions` object:

```
AjaxOptions ajaxOpts = new AjaxOptions
{        
    HttpMethod = "Get",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
};
```

In the view I have this form:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetPeopleData", ajaxOpts))
{
    <div>            
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
}
```

This results in the following HTML:

```
<form action="/People/GetPeopleData" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="Get" id="form0" method="post">
    <div>            
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

When I submit the form I can see that a GET request is sent.

Why does the HTML have `data-ajax-method="Get"` and `method="post"`?
What is the purpose of the `method="post"`?

Comment: Because `Ajax.BeginForm` is unobtrusive (if the user has disabled javascript, it makes a normal submit, and by default `BeginForm()` generates `method="post"`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`@Ajax.BeginForm()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx) helper utilize jQuery unobtrusive AJAX library. If you examine the helper return type, it returns [`System.Web.Mvc.Html.MvcForm`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.mvc.html.mvcform(v=vs.118).aspx), the same return type as [`@Html.BeginForm()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.FormExtensions.BeginForm(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper)) which creates `<form>` tag:

```
public static MvcForm BeginForm(
    this AjaxHelper ajaxHelper,
    AjaxOptions ajaxOptions
)
```

Since all of its overloads don't have parameter which specify HTTP request in [`System.Web.Mvc.FormMethod`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.formmethod(v=vs.118).aspx) enumeration, it uses default `POST` request like `@Html.BeginForm()` has, hence it also writes `method="post"` for default form method if unobstrusive AJAX script is disabled in client side.

The purpose of `data-ajax-method` attribute is to override default submit request behavior when unobtrusive AJAX enabled because its value set by [`AjaxOptions.HttpMethod`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.httpmethod%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) property, and checked by `asyncRequest()` method inside unobtrusive AJAX library (see complete version of the script [here](https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive/blob/master/src/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js)):

```
function asyncRequest(element, options) {
    var confirm, loading, method, duration;

    confirm = element.getAttribute("data-ajax-confirm");
    if (confirm && !window.confirm(confirm)) {
        return;
    }

    loading = $(element.getAttribute("data-ajax-loading"));
    duration = parseInt(element.getAttribute("data-ajax-loading-duration"), 10) || 0;

    $.extend(options, {
        type: element.getAttribute("data-ajax-method") || undefined, // here AJAX method is checked (GET or POST)
        url: element.getAttribute("data-ajax-url") || undefined,
        cache: (element.getAttribute("data-ajax-cache") || "").toLowerCase() === "true",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            var result;
            asyncOnBeforeSend(xhr, method);
            result = getFunction(element.getAttribute("data-ajax-begin"), ["xhr"]).apply(element, arguments);
            if (result !== false) {
                loading.show(duration);
            }
            return result;
        },
        complete: function () {
            loading.hide(duration);
            getFunction(element.getAttribute("data-ajax-complete"), ["xhr", "status"]).apply(element, arguments);
        },
        success: function (data, status, xhr) {
            asyncOnSuccess(element, data, xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Type") || "text/html");
            getFunction(element.getAttribute("data-ajax-success"), ["data", "status", "xhr"]).apply(element, arguments);
        },
        error: function () {
            getFunction(element.getAttribute("data-ajax-failure"), ["xhr", "status", "error"]).apply(element, arguments);
        }
});
```

**Note:** You can see list of attributes which corresponds to each properties of `AjaxOptions` in [this reference](https://dotnetthoughts.net/jquery-unobtrusive-ajax-helpers-in-aspnet-core/).